# Visual Studio Empty asp.net Project Causes Error of not finding resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have created asp.net empty project in visual studio 2013 with c#. So whenever I tries to get any view I get error of Resource not found. However, If I create a internet application template project it works fine.

So here is my URL: `http://localhost:43763/Home/About`

**Home Controller (Home.cs)**

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class Home : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**About View (About.cshtml)**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<h2>About</h2>
```

**Here is RouteConfig.cs**

```
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller name from Home to HomeController .i  think  maybe  this is  the reason

The Controllers Folder contains the controller classes responsible for handling user input and responses.

MVC requires the name of all controllers to end with "Controller".

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {

    }
```

Comment: Yep. All controller classes need to end with `Controller`.